# Sonarqube vs sonarscanner

Tags: sonarqube, code-analysis, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I have a very big confusion that what is the use of sonar scanner when we have sonarqube server? when I analyzed a project with soarqube server it made an analysis and worked well. I am still in confusion why we need scanners too.

Does it required when integrating with eclipse or maven or github? I did research on this but unable to get exact answer to satisfy myself.

Answer (score 3):

Sonarqube provides the intelligence to execute a scan.

SonarScanner is the scanner developed in-house by Sonar Source the organisation that developed SonarQube too.

SonarScanner is one of many scanners available for our use. maven, gradle, ant, Jenkins are few others. Which means maven is not dependent on SonarScanner, and you can simply use maven instead of SonarScanner. Hope that helps. That said I don't understand what you mean by I analysed with Sonarqube! Because to my knowledge Sonarqube server does not perform analysis and it needs a tool to the job

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Shiva. Yes i analysed a project creating ci pipeline github--jenkins--sonarqube. I didnt installed sonar scanner but my source code got analysed. then what is the need of sonar scanner if sonarqube does all by itself

Comment: @Philip so we don't need sonar scanner?

Comment: your answer is more confusing.

Comment: If SonarQube was a game console. Sonarscanner is one among many joystick